# When or where is a callback added through add_done_callback triggered?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-asyncio

I'm reading the following code with Visual Studio Code (VSCode) Debugger.

```py
import asyncio


async def main():
    print("OK Google. Wake me up in 1 seconds.")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Wake up!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main(), debug=False)
```

I could understand the main flow of the program that schedules a callback to sleep the process for a second, but it was difficult to follow when or where [_run_until_complete_cb](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9fdc64cf1266b6d5bf0503847b5c38e5edc53a14/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L180) is called?

After the main coroutine is executed, this function/callback is called to stop an event loop by setting a _stopping flag to be True. It is, however, originally appended to a _callbacks internal property in the Future class through [add_done_callback](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/futures.py#L193) or called soon if the future is done.

```py
def add_done_callback(self, fn, *, context=None):
    """Add a callback to be run when the future becomes done.
    The callback is called with a single argument - the future object. If
    the future is already done when this is called, the callback is
    scheduled with call_soon.
    """
    if self._state != _PENDING:
        self._loop.call_soon(fn, self, context=context)
    else:
        if context is None:
            context = contextvars.copy_context()
        self._callbacks.append((fn, context))
```

Either case, it's registered with the event loop by a call_soon method and called at the next iteration at the end. But the future haven't done yet at the moment added the else clause above.

My question is where or when the future is done to proceed with _run_until_complete_cb to the else clause? Since the VSCode debugger just skips or ignores the line of code that calls the method on Future and Task instances somehow, so the flow jumps right into the call_soon in _run_until_complete_cb.

What exactly happened after finishing the main coroutine? Does someone have any ideas or hints about a clean-up process of the asyncio module to stop the event loop or a way to look into the methods on Future or Task by the VSCode debugger?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to debug into asyncio then you want to [set `"justMyCode": true` in your `launch.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode). That will have the debugger trace into 3rd-party code, including the stdlib.